# Mysql Percona crushes the table while trying to create a unique index on fields where there is a generated one

Tags: mysql, percona

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
`user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`params` JSON,
`hash` VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(`params`)),
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `tasks_user_id_users_id_fk` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

then i try to add a unique index on user_id and hash, i tried to do it during the table create, but there were a problem with the foreign key, so i decided to do it separately.

```
ALTER TABLE tasks   
ADD  UNIQUE INDEX `tasks_user_id_hash_unique_idx` (`user_id`, `hash`);
```

Then i get strange problem error 1146

```
Table '<dbname>.tasks' doesn't exist
```

Since then strange errors 
1. I cannot delete it while it exists and i cannot do with it anything, cause it does not exist. After mysql reload I get the table deleted but if i try to create it again:
    Error Code: 1813
    Tablespace '`<dbname>`.`tasks`' exists.

I found the decision for unique field, i simply genereate md5( hash + user_id) UNIQUE. But How can I get rid of that problem which still exists and what is going on. It looks like a BUG in mysql Percona 5.7.14-7

so the right way to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
`user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`params` JSON,
`hash` VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(CONCAT(`params`,`user_id`))) UNIQUE,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `tasks_user_id_users_id_fk` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)
 )ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But, again, the question with the ghosts still exists after the first tries!

Comment: Well, you are showing the definition for the table `tasks` and then trying to create an index on `taxtasks`.  I'm not surprised that MySQL is confused.  I am.

Comment: it is simply a typo, fixed the typo.

Comment: After the crash the meta data saved in information_schema in INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES for the table remained. So it is an obvious bug in mysql, that the try to create a composite key in that case crashes the table and leaves the ghost namespaces in inf schema. How i solved it - I restored the db from backup on the date before i examined the composite unique key on the user_id and hash fields. Always make backups, twice a day is a good practice!